# Converting git log output into Json array not working(Node.js)

Tags: json, node.js, git

I am trying to obtain log of all the branches and then save it in Json file. My code currently doesn't output an array in my json file. How do I do this?
I am very new to node.js and Javascript in general.

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var branchesObj;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
console.log(stdout)
var fs = require('fs');
console.log("Creating branches log ..."); 

function getBranches(stdout) {  

branchesObj = JSON.parse(branches);

branches = JSON.stringify(stdout.split(/\r?\n/));
var lines = branches.toString().split('commit');
var results = new Array();
lines.forEach(function(line) {
    var parts = line.split('/\r?\n/');
    results[parts[0]] = parts[1];
});

console.log(results);
fs.writeFile('Branches.json', results);
};
fs.writeFile('Branches.json', stdout);
}
exec("git branch--all", puts);
```

Currently this is what my JSON file looks like and it doesn't have the brackets around the array e.g. Branches = [
{
}]:

```
* master
remotes/origin/38563
remotes/origin/53035
remotes/origin/AVA_SAMPSON
remotes/origin/AlexTMP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you want:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var fs = require('fs');

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { 
   var branches = JSON.stringify(stdout.split(/\r?\n/).map(function(e) { return e.substring(2);}).filter(function(e) { return e; }));
   fs.writeFile('Branches.json', branches);
}
exec("git branch --all", puts);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I get the branch name from "git log --all"

Comment: now it has just put that whole data in square brackets, it's still not spliting each one of them

Comment: To get branches, use `git branch`.

Comment: I am trying get all the branches

Comment: Also, I have update my code now, now it doesn't show me the brackets for my array

Comment: Well looking at your updated answer, all you are doing is writing the output of `git log --all` to `Branches.json`. Out of curiosity, what is your use case? In other words, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: How can I split my data so that it shows in a json array, I want it to be a json array. I am creating a dashboard for out team, to monitor changes on each branch, or to see the list of branch in a drop down, then users using those branches

Comment: I have updated my code, now all I want to do is split it so that I can get all the branches in a json array

Comment: I've edited the answer to contain the code you need. Please mark it as the accepted answer if it works for you.

Comment: One more thing, How do put {} for each branch?

Comment: I need it to be in this format `[
    {"branch 1"}, 
    {"branch 2"}, 
]`

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: so how can I make it valid?

Comment: It is valid as it is, without the brackets. Why do you think you need brackets?

Comment: So I can iterate over it and pick each branch and display it in the dropdown

Comment: You don't need brackets for that. Just iterate over the array.